# Html.DropDownList returns an empty string in IE, works fine in FF

Tags: html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlist that is simply a list of strings (salutations). When I submit the form, the field is an empty string no matter what value is selected. 
In firefox, it works exactly as expected...but not in IE.
 `<tr>
            <td>Salutation : </td><td><%= Html.DropDownList("Salutation", new SelectList(Salutations.SalutationList, Model.Salutation), "")%></td>
        </tr>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I faced this problem today with html.dropdownlist. The resolution was similar (use the long form of SelectList).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing this instead.

```
<tr>
    <td>Salutation : </td><td><%= Html.DropDownList("Salutation", new SelectList(Salutations.SalutationList.Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }), "value", "text", Model.Salutation), "")%></td>
</tr>
```